# Executing Java Mission Control from command line

Tags: linux, jmc

I have  copied the JMC 7.0 binaries in linux. Any idea on how to start the application from commandline or do we need GUI to be enabled in linux ?

Thanks,
Naveed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no headless mode of JMC, but you can start a recording and open it from the shell.

```
java -XX:StartFlightRecording:filename=dump.jfr -version
./jmc -openFile dump.jfr
```